# Стилистическая корректность сочетания

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Имеется текст:

И тогда Профессор неожиданно заявил – неподалеку же есть  еще один монастырь, о котором я даже не упоминала, но он тоже хороший и, как мне нравится,  старый...Что и говорить! Мы развернулись **и в угасающем дне** помчались в Градац. Ведь именно об этом я мечтала сегодня **утром**...

Можно  сказать **"помчались в угасающем дне"** или надо редактировать? В чем некорректность сочетания?

Comment: А что это означает?

Comment: В каком смысле?  В угасающем дне - это в сумерках.

Comment: Думаю, редактировать. Смысл не прозрачен. Звучит плоховато. Чего-то художественного и эстетического здесь нет. Вот "угасающим днём" лучше.

Comment: А мне нравится. "Угасающим днём" не пойдёт.

Comment: Ну вот, разные мнения. Лучше, наверное, не трогать. А что это, авторский неологизм?

Comment: Наверно, неологизм, да. А нельзя переделать, например "в отблесках угасающего дня"?

Comment: Переделать-то можно (то есть предложить другой вариант), но надо осмысленно править. Мне кажется, что отблески здесь будут не на месте. Сейчас инфостиль в моде, лишние слова не любят.

Comment: Шаронушка, не трожь Автора! *Я мечтою ловил уходящие тени, / 
Уходящие тени погасавшего дня...*

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо! К вашему совету я уж точно прислушаюсь.

Comment: Хотя бы "_в сумраке_ угасавшего дня" (или даже" сквозь сумрак") нужно добавить, чтобы "дно не угасало" :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетание **в угасающем дне** звучит непривычно, но [гуглокниги](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1047&bih=465&tbm=bks&ei=cBNJXoGmFvL0qwHS2rjIDQ&q=%22%D0%92%20%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%22&oq=%22%D0%92%20%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...76984.77661.0.78027.4.4.0.0.0.0.138.378.0j3.3.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.fu0cGjeRb8o) находят около десятка цитат, половина из которых приходится на качественно редактируемые журналы советских времён. И как это часто бывает, познакомившись с различными примерами употребления, перестаёшь видеть в этом что-то крамольное.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, теперь непременно буду заглядывать в "гуглокниги".

Comment: @Sharon В гугл-книгах часто можно встретить чистый бред. Они-то точно хуже Нацкорпуса (по качеству).

Comment: Я должна вам поверить на слово? По-моему, обычное цитирование художественной литературы. Если не доверяете источнику, посмотрите, что за автор, найдите его в наших поисковиках.

Comment: @oleedd Поделюсь своим опытом. Нужен совсем небольшой практический навык, чтобы научиться отличать качественные издания от всякого ширпотреба и самиздата. После освоения этого навыка гуглокники сразу становятся не мене ценным источником, чем Нацкорпус. К тому же он избавлен существенного недостатка — ошибок автоматического распознавания.

Comment: Контекст большинства литературных источников с выражением "в угасающем дне" связан не с _передвижением в нём_ рассказчика (или персонажа), а с наблюдаемым на его фоне цветовым явлением: обычно "в угасающем дне" там что-нибудь розовеет, светлеет или иначе выделяется, - это чисто _визуальный_ образ. Видимо, поэтому в нашем случае странно звучит "мы в угасающем дне помчались" - будто собственные силуэты "в нём" наблюдают.

Comment: @Alex_ander Согласен с Вами, но по ссылке есть два примера известных советских писателей с похожим на нужное употреблением (особенно: "в угасающем дне ... мы пересекли вторую реку"). Полагаю, что такая метафоричность вполне допустима.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, здесь подразумевалось (автором): «в угасающем свете дня».
В КРЯ есть похожие примеры:
Она долго ходила вдоль тропинки; при исчезающем свете дня я не мог рассмотреть ее лица, тем более что кровать моя стояла довольно далеко от окна; но по ее походке, по быстроте движений я заключал, что она была молода, и в воображении уже приискивал для нее сходство с чертами прежде знакомых мне красавиц. [Е. А. Ган. Суд света (1840)]

Comment: Спасибо. Сочетание "в угасающем свете дня"  встречается в текстах, но и авторское выражение нашлось тоже.

Answer (score 1):

> В чем некорректность сочетания?

Можно ли сказать "в дне" вместо "днём"? Нет. И никакое прилагательное/причастие это не исправит. Но может сгладить звучание.

"Днём" точно используется. Предлагаю заменить на "угасающим днём".

А в текущем варианте оно звучит как склонение слова "дно".

Comment: Пожалуйста, в начале ответа запишите исправленное предложение. Наверное, лучше "в угасающих сумерках".  Но может быть, это "авторская находка"? Грамматика верная (выбор падежа).

Comment: Угасающим днем, то есть вечером? Так вообще не говорят.

Comment: Не уверен, что "угасающим днём" будет стилистически удачно, но зато грамматика верная. "В" как бы подводит к необычному сочетанию. А "угасающим днём" подразумевает, что все знакомы с таким выражением. || "В угасающем дне" тем более не говорят. "В угасающих сумерках" звучит красиво, но разве сумерки могут угасать? Они и подразумевают угасание света.

Comment: Народ пишет, например: В угасающих сумерках Напп-стрит казалась темным ущельем, отлитым из мрака посреди четырехэтажных кирпичных зданий.https://dom-knig.com/read_89739-36

Comment: Здесь лучше разобраться, уместно ли говорить, что сумерки угасают. Сумерки символизируют начало ночи, а не свет. Угасание - исчезание света. Сказать можно разное, "люди схавают", но нужно понимать, что мы говорим.

Comment: Спасибо, oleedd. Мне сказали, что авторские неологизмы здесь обсуждать нежелательно. Это не в рамках форума.

Comment: Интересно, где сказали. Не вижу такого комментария.

Comment: Вот здесь сказали, что мои вопросы некорректны, даже проголосовали за их закрытие  Но я не очень поняла смысл.  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458415/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment471735_458415

Comment: Не слушайте shampar'а. Этот сайт предусматривает всё, что связано с русским языком. Все запреты здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask и здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic